# Is Dot Net HttpClient Unexpectedly Caching Responses?

Tags: c#, .net, wininet, http-caching

I'm attempting to write a curl-like tool that demonstrates the effect of various HTTP caching headers on dot net's HttpClient class.

In my initial attempt I'm pointing the tool at one of my internal web services that does not specify any caching information in the response and examining the header of the response.

I expect to see that the request is re-sent each time and executed on the server, returning a new but identical set of content each time (for the purpose of this test, the content is static on the server). But, instead, each request after the first returns much more quickly than the first and includes a new header Age that was not present in the very first response.  This indicates to me that the HttpClient in my command-line tool is returning the response from cache, not placing a new request.

Here is the first request with the response headers:

```
HTTP:>GET http://myserver:8058/path1/path2
Status 200 OK (OK in 00:00:00.3235905):
Date = Sat, 08 Jul 2017 15:55:22 GMT
Server = Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Content-Length = 150867
Content-Type = application/json; charset=utf-8
```

and here is the request from the same session of my curl tool, a little while later:

```
HTTP:>GET http://myserver:8058/path1/path2
Status 200 OK (OK in 00:00:00.0188433):
Date = Sat, 08 Jul 2017 15:55:22 GMT
Server = Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Age = 312
Content-Length = 150867
Content-Type = application/json; charset=utf-8
```

and finally, after I stop and start my program, here's another request from the new instance:

```
HTTP:>GET http://myserver:8058/path1/path2
Status 200 OK (OK in 00:00:00.0517271):
Date = Sat, 08 Jul 2017 15:55:22 GMT
Server = Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Age = 528
Content-Length = 150867
Content-Type = application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The last one I find even more difficult to understand as I was under the impression (from reading this: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) that caching is maintained *per instance* of HttpClient.

This seems to continue forever with Age increasing each request.  The only way to get back to the original response is to use Internet Explorer and delete temporary internet files.

**[Additional Info]** After leaving my command line application open for a couple of hours I repeated the request and received a response identical to the original, without the Age header.  So it appears that, if HttpClient was caching the response, that cache expired after a couple of hours.

Can anyone tell me if I'm correct that HttpClient is performing internal caching in this case, and if so, why it's doing so in the absence of any caching-related response headers and what policy it's using?